# Prestashop menu no subcategories

Tags: php, prestashop

As I can do, not to show the subcategories in the menu prestashop.

as I have over 1000 subcategories.

thanks

Comment: I do not understand the negative feedback. is a question not very technical but not a bad question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go into Prestashop admin interface.
2. Choose Modules
3. Choose "Categories block" module, and click "Configure"
4. In the "Maximum depth" field, enter "1" to only show categories on the Categories menu.

Comment: Nothing happens when I edit this from default 4 to 1. I have upto 6 sub-categories in each category and in the subcategories to depth 8. I only want to show 1-2 depth.